# Using 'find' to create text file, and later deleting files listed

Tags: shell, find, rm

I'm trying to use `find` to create a text file with the result.
And then later be able to delete files, based on that list.

I'm using `find /volume1/video/ -iname "sample"` to give me the results.
How do I get this into a file, and then how to remove folders based on this list (also non empty).

Comment: Could you clarify a bit. Do you want to create a file that has name  "sample"? When do you want to delete it?

Answer (score 2):

With GNU tools:

```
find /volume1/video/ -iname sample -printf '%h\0' | xargs -r0 rm -rf
```

Or if you need the intermediate file:

```
find /volume1/video/ -iname sample -printf '%h\0' > file
< file xargs -r0 rm -rf
```

Comment: Prefer the "in-core" version.

Answer (score 1):

To get the results of `find /volume1/video/ -iname "sample"` to a file `x.txt`, all you need to do is to use redirection:

```
find /volume1/video/ -iname "sample" > x.txt
```

Now, if I understand your question correct, you need to delete directories listed in the file `x.txt`. For that, you need to iterate over file x.txt and use `dirname` and `rm`:

```
while IFS= read -r line ; do
    dname=$(dirname "$line")
    rm -rf "$dname"
done < x.txt
```

You may want to be cautious here and check the contents of `x.txt` before running the above loop.

Comment: `$(cat x.txt)` can be shortened to `$(<x.txt)` but neither should be used. That is a case for `while read line; do...`

Comment: Hmm, If I just give rm -rf $line it is not enough?

Answer (score 0):

To get the results into a file, you just have to pipe the command's output to a file.

```
find /volume1/video/ -iname "sample" > output
```

Now, I am assuming you need to delete all the files that we got in the output file. So for that, you can read all the lines of the file and use a `rm -rf` inside the `while` loop.

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
rm -rf "$line"
done < output.txt
```

Comment: If there are no newlines in the paths...

Comment: My bad. Changed it.

Comment: Why you set recursive deletion and force attributes in "rm" ? That's dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is redirection of the output and you use the `>` for that:

```
find /volume1/video/ -iname "sample" > output_file_name
```

**However proceeding to work with the output only works if the pathnames under `/volume1/video` do not contain any special characters**.

You could have the following 2 lines in your output:

```
/volume1/video/abc/sample
/volume1/video/def/sample
```

Which **could** be a single file with as name the string:
 `"/volume1/video/abc/sample\n/volume1/video/def/sample"`

It would be better to generate the output file with NUL characters as separators, as these cannot be part of a filename on Unix/Linux systems:

```
find /volume1/video/ -iname "sample" -print0 > output_file_name
```

Comment: The only problem is `\n`. And you need `IFS= read -r ...`

Comment: @HaukeLaging I fail to see how you *after generating the file* would be able to determine the difference with the a filename with the embedded newline and the two separate files with the resp. lines as filenames (the could exist all three). Or would that command generate a different output file?

Comment: That would be magic, indeed. You have to take care for that when creating the file. I clean solution would be to use `-print0` and use the file as input for `xargs -0` or read it with `while read -d $'\0' line; do`. It should be possible to escape the newlines, too. But that seems more complicated to me. You would have to pass the paths as parameters to a program (piping from `find` would not work) which replaces `\n` by `\\\n` (one backslash before the newline).